# Отладка программ Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, gdb

Досталась в наследство программа Over 100 тысяч сток кода.
Когда в Qt Creator запускаю в режиме дебага, в консоль каждые 10 секунд сыпется 12 сообщений

```
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function
```

Перерыл все циклы и таймеры, не могу найти что вызывает это.

Как я могу узнать, какая функция вызывает это?

Программа многопоточная, точки останова не очень помогают
Использую `Windows 10. Qt 5.9.2`.

Comment: тут смотрели https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36968475/how-to-debug-invalid-parameter-passed-to-c-runtime-function ?

Comment: смотрел. Не осилил, как мне это к себе применить..покурю еще там

Comment: Платформу укажите

Comment: @Cerbo дописал в вопросе.

Comment: Пока пытаюсь запускать из консоли gdb. Получаю такой же вывод. Возможно стоит использовать какие-то ключи

Comment: Это из функций WinAPI сообщение, в указанном @magrif посте предлагают поставить точку останова на функцию OutputDebugStringA и когда остановится надо смотреть стек

Comment: Прошагал в дебаггере. Первый такой вывод появляется на `webmanager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);` похоже на это https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-70795

Comment: Поскольку Qt5.9 это LTS версия, я бы перешёл для начала на 5.9.9

Comment: я бы поставил брейк на функции вывода (`write()` в nix-мире, в win скорей всего `WriteFile()`) и посмотрел бы полный `backtrace`... если ложноположительных срабатываний слишком много, то можно сделать условный брейк, который срабатывает только при печати в `stderr`... не знаю правда насколько gdb под win всё это умеет делать или нет...

Comment: Весь вывод в программе через qDebug(). Ни один этот вывод не печатает это.

Comment: Обновил Windows, обновил Qt до 5.9.8 - проблема ушла